# printing A3 in inkscape

Tags: printing, inkscape

I'm trying to print a A3 inkscape project with a Brother MFC-J6920DW.
The document size and orientation are set to A3 (297X420) landscape
but when printing it comes out as a A4 containing only a part of the document.
i tried to set the printer property’s size and orientation but they are greyed (orientation ) out or do not exist ( papersize )
can someone help please

Comment: I use Inkscape 0.48.3.1 r9886 for Linux

Answer (score 0):

What about `File->Print->Preferences->Printing Shortcuts->Paper sizes->A4`

Comment: This option is not existent in the version of inkscape i use. I use Inkscape 0.48.3.1 r9886 for Linux

Comment: Have a look at [Bug:Print page size is incorrect](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/630635)